# why distinct() doesn't return unique Integer items?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

```
return repository.loadItems(id)
    .take(1)
    .flatMapIterable { item -> item }
    .map { item -> item.clientId}
    .toList()
    .toFlowable()
    .distinct();


fun loadItems(id: Int): Flowable<List<Item>> {
    return dao.loadItems(id)
}
```

I fetch List map to List and want to filter and save only unique ones, while distinct() doesn't work it brings as much items as the initial list is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`distinct` filters out duplicates that pass through it. Since you applied it at the wrong place, it only receives a `List` object which by itself is distinct.

Apply `distinct` before the `toList` to get the unrolled `List` get filtered before it gets aggregated into a new `List`.

```
return repository.loadItems(id)
    .take(1)
    .flatMapIterable { item -> item }
    .map { item -> item.clientId}
    .distinct()  // <------------------------------------------------------
    .toList()
    .toFlowable()
```